# How can I find the nonce inverse of a particular bitcoin transaction?

Tags: elliptic-curves, cryptography

How can I calculate the Y axis Of the R value in the Eliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm (Ecdsa). The reason I said 'y' axis of the 'r' value is because I believe the y axis is the nonce used to calculate the s value in Ecdsa. S = K^-1 (Z + RA) MOD Please correct me if I'm wrong.

The nonce inverse (k^-1) ...I'm trying to sign the digital signature I want to make. Is there any solution to this problem. I would love to know. Thanks in advance. (if the question is not understood please let me know down in the comments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly: you're trying to run your own example of ECDSA (from your other closed post about the same issue). You have your "nonce", which is otherwise seems to be known as your secret key/ephemeral key: in this case a random element $k \mod q$, where $q$ is a prime that is a public parameter that I can only assume you know.

In order to find $k^{-1} \mod q$, you should use Bézout's Lemma that provides you with the following: if you let $g = \gcd(k,q)$, then there exists $u,v \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that 
$$uk+vq=g.$$
Noting in this case that $g =1$ since $q$ is prime, we have that 
$$uk+vq  \equiv uk  \equiv g \equiv 1 \mod q$$
hence $u=k^{-1}$. Therefore your objective should be to find this value $u$. To compute this value one often uses the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).

Comment: Noted....  Such nice computation I must say.....so that means to find  K^-1 I will have to use the Euclidean algorithm in the equation? Please do clarify

Comment: Yes, you will need to use the **extended** Euclidean algorithm on **the pair** $(k,q)$

Comment: For example..... I grabbed some of my ideas from this video https://youtu.be/6TI5YOpnrgI ...... At least could you be able to skip it to where they talk about the nonce.... It's on the two minute mark of the video.... I'll just like to know if that was a coincidence or its how it is meant to be

Comment: For this algorithm you do need a nonce/random/secret key, this is not a coincidence. And you do need to find its modular inverse.

Comment: I do understand that but if you also look at the video....  The  X axis was the r value and the Y axis of the nonce multiplied by the generator point is the nonce inverse which was 17

Comment: @DaveKent I looked at the video and cannot find what you're referencing. Rather than pointing me at the video, can you instead tell me precicely what you're asking about/have a question over?

Comment: Alright...  I'm just using the video for reference purposes.... My question is.... Can K^-1 always be the Y axis of the R value since k was used to multiply G to make R which is the X axis in the result of the equation? ( referring to the video earlier on the two minute mark )  Note: r is the X axis,  while k^-1 is the Y axis (I couldn't find a way to express my question... Please understand).

Comment: @DaveKent Ahh, I see what you mean now. That was a coincidence in the video, you're correct. It just so happened that when they computed $$kG = \underbrace{G + G + \cdots + G}_{\text{$k$-many}}$$ that the $y$-coordinate of the result had the same value as $k^{-1}$. That does _not_ happen in general.

Comment: One more question....  Can I find the nonce inverse without the nonce? Not calculate

Comment: @DaveKent No, to find the inverse of an element you need to know the element whose inverse you're looking for.